# C# Exception not thrown after installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installation, wix, wix3.8

We are using a try-catch-block in `Main()` to catch all Exceptions of an Application and to write them into a lgo file. Everything works fine in Release configuration within VS2012. Exceptions are thrown and saved to a file.

After creating an installer using WIX and installing the application, the exception is directly thrown (and shown as a dialog), but not catched by the try-catch-block in Main() and therefore not saved in the file anymore. How can I catch the Exception in `Main()`?

This is the code in the Program.cs:

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLog.SaveExceptionCloseApp(Program.RuntimeGUID, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "()", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "saved to file"? What exactly are you doing? Provide us some code that is working while Debugging, but not after installation.

Comment: Added code of the Program.cs

Comment: Could it be that the Exception occurs because once you've installed your app via a WiX-generated MSI, the installation folder does not contain all the required binaries? Then execution would then fail *before* Main, so wouldn't be caught by your try/catch block. I'd also suggest using the FusLogVw tool to check whether all the required assemblies are available.

Comment: Are you sure that WiX is building the setup with the correct build configuration? Might be the issue that it's using the Debug configuration which is representing an earlier version of your code.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS no, the app is running and we are already inside the Main when the Exception is thrown

Comment: @Dr.Coconut I checked the build configurations. They are all set to Release.

Comment: Is it definitely the same exception that is being thrown? Can you say for sure that it's thrown in the same location or might it be that the error is thrown inside your method `SaveExceptionCloseApp` when running the installed version? If you can say it for sure, you probably have the stack-trace of the exception. Could you include it in your question?

Comment: This code can only ever show an exception when you run it with a debugger.  Without one the Application.ThreadException event is raised.  Consider writing your own event handler for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for us:
@Hans Passant: Thank you for the solution.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {           
        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }

    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionLog.SaveExceptionCloseApp(Program.RuntimeGUID, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "()", e.Exception);
    }
```